# Legend Options - R Raster Legend

Tags: r, legend, r-raster, legend-properties

How do I remove the black box surrounding the raster legend?  More generally, where can I find the documentation for the options for R raster legends?

```
   require(raster)
        data(volcano)
        r <- raster(volcano)
        plot(r, col=topo.colors(100), legend=FALSE, axes=FALSE)
        r.range <- c(minValue(r), maxValue(r))
        plot(r, legend.only=TRUE, col=topo.colors(100),
             legend.width = 2,
             axis.args=list(at=seq(r.range[1], r.range[2], 25),
                            labels=seq(r.range[1], r.range[2], 25), 
                            cex.axis=0.6),
             legend.args=list(text='Elevation (m)', side=4, font=2, line=2.5, cex=0.8))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `par(bty='n')` before ploting the legend:

```
par(bty= "n") # remove the box
plot(r, legend.only=TRUE, col=topo.colors(100),
     legend.width = 2,
     axis.args=list(at=seq(r.range[1], r.range[2], 25),
                    labels=seq(r.range[1], r.range[2], 25), 
                    cex.axis=0.6),
     legend.args=list(text='Elevation (m)', side=4, font=2, line=2.5, cex=0.8))
par(bty= "o") # set the box
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any advice for finding fixes such as these more generally?  I searched the documentation for the plot raster legend and obviously this fix is separate from that.

Comment: Usually, specific `plot()` documentation only describe their specific part, so for plotting options that are generic (not specific to raster) you have to look at generic `plot()` documentation (`?plot` then select base R )